# Where to find documentation about 12.04's X11 configuration?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, x11

From man pages to google results, most documentation explains how to interact with `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, which simply doesn't exist in my out-of-the-iso vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 installation.

So, where do I get documentation that actually explains how to interact with my xserver on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go to

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config

for the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

I always start out with the man pages

```
man xorg.conf
```

Will show you the manual for Xorg without the requirement of internet access web browser, or a working X. So it's especially useful if you shut down X to reconfigure something ,and can't get it working properly.

'q'         - quit man page
'page up'   - browse page up
'page down' -  browse page down
'/'         - enter search field

Comment: the problem is, that my man-Page for xorg.conf talks about a single file most of the time, but this file doesn't exist. I only have an xorg.conf.d folder with some files inside, I seemed to use them incorrectly and `man xorg.conf` didn't help me understand why.

Comment: It does not exist under /etc/X11/xorg.conf , because ubuntu automatically generates it. If you want to use one. Just create the xorg.conf file there and start editing the entries you require.

Comment: I did and then couldn't start my Ubuntu.